# Hide all element with #id not in array given

Tags: html, jquery

I have an array containing IDs of element like :

```
let array = ['id1','id2'];
```

How can I hide all element that it's `#id` is not in array that is given before.

```
<div id="id1" class="shown">
<div id="id2" class="shown">
<div id="id3" class="shown">

<!-- Expected Result -->
<div id="id1" class="shown">
<div id="id2" class="shown">
<div id="id3" class="">
```

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and use the available [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype). Use [`.classList`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop over all the elements with `id` attribute. Test if the ID is in the array, and set the class appropriately.

```
$("div[id]").each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("shown", !array.includes(this.id));
});
```

Comment: Thanks just exactly what I want. One question, if I have a `p` tag inside the `div` how we select the `p` child of  that `div` ? We can say add `.html('its hidden')` to the `p` child

Comment: `$(this).find("p")`

Comment: Nope. I've tried that. But in my case it selecting all the `div`s even the shown one.

Comment: That should be in an `if` statement that decides whether it should say that it's hidden or not.

Comment: `if (array.includes(this.id)) { $(this).find("p").html("It's hidden"); }`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `.each` loop to iterate through your  div .Inside this get `id` and check if its not there in array using `.indexOf` if true hide that div. i.e :

```
$("div[id*=id]").each(function() {
  //get id
  var id_ = $(this).attr("id")
  //check if not in array
  if (array.indexOf(id_) == -1) {
    $(this).removeClass("shown") //hide it
  }
})
```

Comment: They want to add or remove the `shown` class based on the condition, not loop over the `shown` elements.

Comment: Thank you it'll works. Looks cool but if I have so much values in array it is taking so much effort to working with the index

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding this is my code.

```
let array = ['id1','id2'];
$('div').each(function(){
  var thisid = $(this).attr('id');
  if (thisid&&thisid.substr(0,2)=='id'){
    if (array.indexOf(thisid)==-1){
       $('#'+thisid).removeClass('shown');
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate brute force option is to remove all the instances of the `shown` class then add them back with a selector built from using `join` on the array.

In realitiy use [Barmars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67980375/4665) answer instead.

```js
let array = ['id1','id2', 'id4'];
//Build a selector from the array
let selector =  "#" + array.join(",#");
//Brute force shown off
//$("div[id]").removeClass("shown");
//Or a little less brutish - may not even need add depending on your needs
$("div[id]").not(selector).removeClass("shown");
//Add the class from the array.
$(selector).addClass("shown");
//console.log(selector);
```

```css
div:not(.shown) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1" class="shown">1</div>
<div id="id2" class="shown">2</div>
<div id="id3" class="shown">3</div>
<div id="id4" >4</div>
```